# How to monitor cpu and memory usage itself in Haskell program

Tags: haskell, memory-management, monitoring, cpu-usage

In **Haskell** program, **how to monitor CPU and memory usage by the program itself?**

In my program, there could be idle time because of user does not make any request.
At that time, I want to `evaluate` statistics to trigger GC.
However, I want to *record* statistics not by *static* methods but *lazy* method.
So, I want to design the program could monitor itself to find the relative idle timing to `evaluate`.

I've searched web and Hackage about {monitoring,cpu,memory} libraries, but I could find only total CPU and memory usages, not a program itself.

Are there any monitoring libraries exist that I skipped?
Or do I have to make something myself?
If I have to make it myself, what should I study for? It should works with Windows, Linux and OS X.

## Update

`currentBytesUsed` in `GHC.Stats` gives memory usages. Thanks danidiaz.
I'm still finding that monitoring CPU usages.

P.S. I do not want to profile it. I have done it many times already....

Comment: Have you looked in [GHC.Stats](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/GHC-Stats.html)?

Comment: @danidiaz Thanks, I didn't see that. `currentBytesUsed` seems memory usage. It works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if profiling is enough for you, or if you need live monitoring, but there is a lot of profiling possibilities described in the haskell docs https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html

There is also remote monitoring

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ekg

Comment: I have done many profiling with GHC and something other with `criterion`.   However, What I want is that monitoring a program's CPU usage in live.

Comment: My purpose is not tuning program, but **find the moments that usage of CPU is low by itself** during running it.

Comment: `ekg` may help monitoring and reporting something. However, it seems that does not help CPU usage by itself. To utilize `ekg`, I need a method to get CPU usage first.